# LDAP - Only Allow Users In A Group To Sign On,

Tags: python, flask, ldap, flask-login

I am building a small Flask application for my organization.
I have my application working with LDAP, in that anyone in our organization can log into it. But, I want to restrict the users that can use this application to those that are in a certain group.

I am using flask_ldap3_login paired with Flask-login to login users.

This is what I have that works with the whole organization. 
I am not sure what else I need to add (or remove) into this too restrict the valid users to only those in a certain group (If it is even possible).

```
'''

class Config:
   LDAP_HOST = 'domain.local'
   LDAP_BASE_DN = 'dc=domain, d=local'
   LDAP_USER_DN = 'ou=employee'
   LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE = 'SUBTREE'
   LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR = 'cn'
   LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR = 'mail'
   LDAP_BIND_USER_DN = 'USER'
   LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD = 'PASS'

'''
```

The hierarchy for the directory I want to access is:

- domain.local

  - groups

    - group I want

      - authorized_users

So mainly I am unsure of what I need to specify to only allow users in this group to be allowed to login. I've tried adding in LDAP_GROUP_DN and LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH_SCOPE but everything either logins in everyone or no one.

I am curious if I am overlooking something, like maybe I am just missing something in the BASE_DN or possibly using the wrong SEARCH_SCOPE. Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing authentication with authorization.
Authentication is proving the user is who he claims.
Once authenticated, it should be possible to read the user entry and the groups he's in to authorize him to use or not the application.